# If all class extends object why can't they all call clone

Tags: java

```java
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cloned().clone();
    }
}

class Cloned implements Cloneable {
}
```

This gives an error, saying it is protected. None of the subclasses of object can call that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Main` doesn't extend `Cloned`. As it stands, `Main` can call `Main.clone`, but not `Cloned.clone`.

The fact that the `clone` method is declared in `Object` doesn't matter here. Apart from public methods, a class can only call **its own inherited methods**. This includes the protected ones from its super-classes, but not protected methods of others (super) classes.

Comment: I'm starting to see that now, I don't think they stress this enough when they discuss protected methods

Comment: I can see that. It's a good question actually, because when sloppy you just say, "protected methods can be called by subclasses", but as you have discovered, that is not the whole truth actually :-)

Comment: How does super.<method> relate to this, why can you call super.clone if super is not of that type

Comment: `super.method()` is not really related. If `B extends A` and both `A` and `B` define a `method()`, then `B` can call `A`'s `method()` through `super.method()`.

Comment: If it's inherited by class `B`! :-)

Answer (score 7):

because `clone()` is protected method in the class Object

if you want `clone()` to be accessed publically, u need to override that method in ur class.

```
@override
public Object clone()
{
    return super.clone();
}
```

Comment: Why? don't we know, that protected members are inherited in the subclasses and anything is a subclass of `java.lang.Object`?

Answer (score 1):

```java
class Main implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
        
      
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```